# Convertir una lista en diccionario

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo una lista como esta:

```
['miCoche1', 'miCoche2', 'miCoche3', 'miCoche4', 'miCoche5']
```

Y quiero convertirla en diccionario.

Hice esta función:

```
for line in mLista:
  palabras = line.rstrip().split()
  for word in palabras:
    if not word in diccionario:
      diccionario[word] = contador
      contador += 1
      break
```

Donde el resultado es este:

```
{'miCoche1': 0, 'miCoche2': 1, 'miCoche3': 2, 'miCoche4': 3, 'miCoche5': 4, 'miCoche6': 5}
```

`Llave 'miCoche1' contenido:1` cuando en realidad quisiera que fuera al revés: `Llave 1: contenido 'miCoche1'`

Comment: ¿Cómo quieres exactamente la salida para esta entrada dada?

Answer (score 3):

Un modo muy directo de hacerlo en python:

```
diccionario = dict(enumerate(set(palabras)))
```

Con `set(palabras)` creas un conjunto que elimina todos los duplicados que puedas tener.

A partir de este iterador, `enumerate` creará parejas de tipo `(índice, elemento)`, autoincrementando el índice.

Finalmente, el constructor `dict` crea un diccionario a partir de una lista de pares, con lo que obtienes el resultado buscado.

Comment: Qué buena! No conocía `enumerate()`
. ¿Sabes si es preferible al `zip()` que sugerí en mi respuesta?

Comment: Lo bueno de `enumerate` es que no requiere saber la longitud de la secuencia, como has necesitado en `range`. Puede usarse con cualquier iterador sin necesidad de convertirlo en lista.

Answer (score 2):

Puede ser una ocasión interesante para usar [`zip()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip):

```
>>> li = ['miCoche1', 'miCoche2', 'miCoche3', 'miCoche4', 'miCoche5']
>>> dict(zip(li, range(len(li))))                                                  
{'miCoche1': 0, 'miCoche2': 1, 'miCoche3': 2, 'miCoche4': 3, 'miCoche5': 4}
```

Con zip "juntas" dos elementos. En este caso, por un lado la lista en sí y por otro un rango de números tan grande como elementos tenga la lista. Luego es cuestión de convertirlo en diccionario.

Si quieres la salida inversa, gira los términos en `zip()`:

```
>>> dict(zip(range(len(li)), li))                                                 
{0: 'miCoche1', 1: 'miCoche2', 2: 'miCoche3', 3: 'miCoche4', 4: 'miCoche5'}
```

Answer (score 0):

sustituye `diccionario[word] = contador` por `diccionario[str(contador)]=word`

`for line in mLista:
  palabras = line.rstrip().split()
  for word in palabras:
    if not word in diccionario:
      diccionario[str(contador)]=word
      contador += 1
      break`

espero te sirva

Comment: tambien pueder usarlo como diccionario[contador]=word, es decir sin la funcion str()

Comment: Gracias por su pronta respuesta solucione mi problema

Comment: @Arturo por qué no marcas la respuesta correcta como aceptada?