# ¿Cómo convertir una lista en un diccionario en python?

Tags: python

tengo una lista que me ha generado la librería `pymysql`, es la siguiente.

```
[{'productId': 1}, {'productId': 2}, {'productId': 3}, {'productId': 4}, {'productId': 5}, {'productId': 6}, {'productId': 7}, {'productId': 8}]
```

Y como podéis observar es para el id de unos productos, me gustaría poder cambiarlo a un diccionario para poder ejecutar esta función

```
if '1' in lista["productId"]:
    [código]
```

Me gustaría obtener este diccionario:

```
{'productId': 1, 'productId': 2, etc...}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Esto: `{'productId': 1, 'productId': 2, etc...}` no es posible, un diccionario por definición, solo maneja claves únicas, no puede tener múltiples `productId`. Podrías eventualmente tener un diccionario así: `{'productId_1': 1, 'productId_2': 2, etc...}`, es decir con claves que no se repitan, pero no le veo mucho sentido a esto. Creo que tu problema va un poco más atrás ¿qué es lo que buscas realmente?

Comment: Por cierto, modifica el titulo, ya que se presta a confusión, tu pregunta no trata de como convertir una lista en un diccionario, ya te han cerrado la misma anteriormente como duplicada, creo que por esto mismo.

Comment: Por qué haces preguntas duplicadas de una pregunta duplicada? Por qué responden a una pregunta que se marcó como duplicada???

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Convertir una lista en diccionario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259430/convertir-una-lista-en-diccionario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes.. Esto: `{'productId': 1, 'productId': 2, etc...}` no puede ser nunca un diccionario válido, por definición un diccionario solo tiene claves únicas, como un diccionario real en papel, no vas a encontrar dos veces la definición de una misma palabra. Eventualmente podrías tener un diccionario con claves versionadas, es decir:

```
diccionario = {'productId_{0}'.format(i): d['productId'] for i, d in enumerate(lista,1)}
print(diccionario)

{'productId_1': 1, 'productId_2': 2, 'productId_3': 3, 'productId_4': 4, 
 'productId_5': 5, 'productId_6': 6, 'productId_7': 7, 'productId_8': 8}
```

Pero seguramente no es lo que buscas, por que tampoco te permitiría hacer algo así:  `if '1' in lista["productId"]`, me parece que más bien, lo que buscas es algo así:

```
diccionario = {'productId': list(d['productId'] for d in lista)}
print(diccionario) 

{'productId': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

Es decir, una lista de valores asociados a la clave `productId` y ahora sí:

```
if 1 in diccionario['productId']:
  print("Existe!")
```

Pero aún así, tampoco es que sea necesario reconvertir la lista, ya que tienes alternativas para verificar directamente la existencia de un valor, por ejemplo:

```
if any(item['productId'] == 1 for item in lista):
  print("Existe!")
```

Comment: Para comprobar que se cumpla un _predicado_ en una lista es mejor usar las funciones [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#any) o [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#all). Por ejemplo, el último if sería: `if any(item['productId'] == 1 for item in lista):`. Si encuentra un caso, devuelve `True` sin necesidad de comprobar el resto de la lista.

Comment: Buen punto @ChemaCortes!